# How to restrict anyone from signning-in using google sign-in in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want only people whom I register or with specified email should be able to use google sign in, rest are not allow to sign in.

example:- I run a institution and I have separate id for my fellow students and I want them to only be able to sign in using that id and otherwise they should not be allowed to use any other Id(email to be more precise).

in my flutter application using firebase-> google_sign_in.

hope I am clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about authentication vs. authorization.

Authentication: Since google is your authentication provider... anyone with a valid google account is authenticated.

Authorization: Who has access to what parts of the application?
You need to implement an authorization system / flow to determine if an authenticated user has access to the app. By default... all users will have NO ACCESS.

How you implement authorization - depends on your backend and how you store user data. If you are using firebase, something like this will help: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access

Answer (score 2):

**bro add some g mails in your firestore those people you want they can access my app if this emails exist in your db then they can google signin otherwise show toast your account is not regirsted by admin**

```
try{
FirbaseFirestore.instance.collection("alloweduser).doc().where("emial",isequalto:123@gmail.com).then(){
Goolglesinin()
{
google signcode
}
}.catch(e)
{
showToast("ask admin to app permission")
}
```